# Create a tree structure from two tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, tree, treeview

So, my problem is that I need to build a tree with data from two tables.

I have the following tables:

```
Category:

| id | parent_id | name           |
|----|-----------|----------------|
| 1  | null      | Category 1     |
| 2  | 1         | Category 1.1   |
| 3  | 2         | Category 1.1.1 |
| 4  | null      | Category 2     |
| 5  | 4         | Category 2.1   |
| 6  | null      | Category 3     |


Layer:

| id | category_id | name    |
|----|-------------|---------|
| 1  | 2           | Layer 1 |
| 2  | 2           | Layer 2 |
| 3  | 3           | Layer 3 |
| 4  | 4           | Layer 4 |
| 5  | 4           | Layer 5 |
| 6  | 5           | Layer 6 |
```

My Category model:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function childrens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function layers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Layer', 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Layer model:

```php
class Layer extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

I'm using the following function to build the category tree:

```php
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $layers = Layer::all();

    return $this->buildTree($categories->toArray(), null);
}


function buildTree($categories, $parent_id)
{
    $categoriesTree = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category['folder'] = true;

         if ($category['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            $childrens = $this->buildTree($categories, $category['id']);
            if ($childrens) {
                $category['childrens'] = $childrens;
            }

            $categoriesTree[] = $category;
        }
    }

    return $categoriesTree;
}
```

The above function works well for categories and the response is:

- Category 1

  - Category 1.1

    - Category 1.1.1
- Category 2

  - Category 2.1
- Category 3

But I want to add layers as child of respective category, like the following:

- **Category 1**

  - **Category 1.1**

    - **Category 1.1.1**

      - Layer 3
    - Layer 1
    - Layer 2
- **Category 2**

  - **Category 2.1**

    - Layer 6
  - Layer 4
  - Layer 5
- **Category 3**

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in your *Category* model with the *Layer* model and eager load it. This way you achieve the same result but with less overhead on your buildTree function because Laravel is doing most of the work:

Category.php model

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function layers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Layer::class);
    }

    // ...
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('layers')->get();

    // ...
}
```

This results in an array like this:

[image: eager loaded layers per category]

Comment: I've tried this approach but don't work well. This is the result: https://pastebin.com/i2siU7Bt 
Thank you!

Comment: It seems like your controller method is missing the `buildTree()` function.

Comment: Exactly this! Worked fine (needs some little adjustments, but nothing that I can't do). Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped!